Cohomology group for trivial group
Let $G$ be a group, $A, B$ be a $G$ - modulo. We can define the n-th Cohomology group of $G$ with coefficient in $A$.
$$H^n(G,A) =\text{Ext }_G^n(\mathbb{Z},A)$$
And the n-th Homology group of $G$ with coefficient in $B$.
$$H_n(G,B)=\text{Tor }^G_n(B,\mathbb{Z})$$
The question is if $G$ is a trivial group i.e $G={0}$, then how to compute $H^n(G,A)$ and $H_n(G,B)$.
I want to start with $\text{Hom }_G(\mathbb{Z},A)$. And $G=0$ gives us the action is trivial. Then I have no idea about this.
Could someone give me some hint(or solution)? Thanks in advance!

What do you mean by $Ext_G$?

@JohnPalmieri I believe $Ext_G$ is intended as an abbreviation for $Ext_{\mathbb Z[G]}$. Here $\mathbb Z[G]$ is the group ring  of $G$ with integer coefficients and $\mathbb Z$ is viewed as a $\mathbb Z[G]$-module with trivial $G$-action.

@AndreasBlass That is what I believe, too, but I want to know that the poster thinks it means.

Conceptually, group cohomology and homology are the derived functors of taking invariants $V \mapsto V^G$ and coinvariants $V \mapsto V_G$ respectively (don't ask me why the "co"s are switched, I didn't do it). When $G$ is the trivial group both of these are the identity functor, which is exact. So its derived functors all vanish.
More explicitly, when $G$ is the trivial group $\mathbb{Z}$ is projective and flat as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module.
